# Rails/ MySQL - Product with sizes and prices

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

What is an elegant way to define model, so one product can have different sizes (and those sizes would have different prices)?

Should I create something like this:

```
rails generate model Product name:string

rails generate model ProductSize size:string product:references

rails generate model SizePrice price:decimal size:references
```

?

I have been looking for an answer but I have not found anything that newbie like me would understand.

Comment: 1. What exactly do you mean by an "elegant design"? 2. Is this question for real or is it a study exercise only? Pricing can be very complicated in a real business.

Comment: 1. Probably to be fast/ flexible in the future. 2. It is a study exercies. I have started learning RoR 1 week ago, and I have not been using MySQL (rather JSON)

Comment: So, you have no idea what you are looking for. Design questions by nature are very broad and primarily opinion based, since requirements, priorities, and personal style all play their parts. If you cannot even describe what you want, it is impossible to provide an objective answer. First write down in words what exactly you want your datamodel to accomplish (describe your entities, their attributes, how the entities are associated with each other) in plain language. You will see, that it will be a lot easier to do the design afterwards.

Comment: What I want is to store the least amount of data in the tables. Assuming that product can have multiple sizes, but a size can also have multiple products. But then there is another level, where size of a product can have a price, but a price might have multiple sizes of multiple different products.

Comment: "but a price might have multiple sizes of multiple different products" What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You need to implement a many-to-many connection using a join table (in your case it would be the SizePrice table). See section 2.4 of this [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).